# Show preloader until content is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I've got a preloader for my site that works but is just counting from 0-100 with a timer  and then the content is displayed, is it possible to amend my code so that it runs from 0-100 while the content is actually loading and only shows the content once loaded?

```js
let counter = 0;
const loaderTimer = setInterval(function() {
  counter++;
  jQuery(".preloader__container__percent").text(counter + "");
  if(counter == 100){
    clearInterval(loaderTimer);
    gsap.to(".preloader", 1, { delay: 0.5, y: "-100%" });
  }
}, 25);
```

```css
.elementor-editor-active .preloader {
display: none;
}

.preloader {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     color: #f2f2f2;
     background-color: #ff635e;
     z-index: 999;
}
 .preloader__container {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     width: 100vw;
     height: 100vh;
}
 .preloader__container__percent {
     font-family: "Alliance Black Italic", Sans-serif;
     font-size: 15vw;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
     .preloader__container__percent {
     font-family: "Alliance Black Italic", Sans-serif;
     font-size: 20vw;
}

 .preloader__container__preload {
     display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.6/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preloader">
  <div class="preloader__container">
        <h1 class="preloader__container__percent"></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to wait until the page is done rendering??

Comment: Yes, so the counter is actually going from 0-100 while the page loads, not just on a set timer which is currently (25)

Comment: How are you loading the rest of the page? Is it being done async?

Comment: im not sure actually, im using elementor for this page

Comment: The percentage based progress bar gives the wrong feeling of taking the current progress for real. A basic approach based on `DOMContentLoaded` and/or `load` will never be capable of even guessing the state of load readiness. The easiest way was to include a css based spinner which immediately is placed in front of the UI which gets switched off by another for instance class-name based css rule where the kill-switch class is set via script on document `load`.

Answer (score -1):

take and display this loader on the content but make it position fixed and z-index 100 and wrap the rest of the content with a div and give this div z-index 50

```html
    <div class="content">
      <!--your content-->
    </div>
    <div class="loader">
      <!--your loader-->
    </div>
```

CSS:

```css
    .content {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 50;
    }
    .loader {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 100;
    }
```

JS:
now delete the loader:

```js
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.querySelector(".loader").remove();
    }, 1000)
```